# Wordpress tinymce editor changes when I call tinymce.init

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, tinymce

I am trying to set the content of a tinymce editor in a plugin and I can change the content but the appearance of the editor changes when I use this code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var name1 = "wprsspostprepend";
if($("#" + name1).length > 0) {

  tinyMCE.init({
    selector : "#wprsspostprepend",
     setup: function (editor) {
    editor.on('init', function () {
      var selector = tinyMCE.get('wprsspostprepend');
      var content =  selector.getContent();
   selector.setContent("<div id='random-wrap'>" + content + "</div>");
    });
  }
});

}


 });
```

I lose all the Wordpress plugin icons from the menu bar and it changes to just a stock editor.

How can I set the content of the editor without changing the appearance?

Comment: Have you tried my answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd imagine that this is due to you prepending everything to the content including the content itself.

Try something like this;

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var name1 = "wprsspostprepend";
    if($("#" + name1).length > 0) {
        tinyMCE.init({
            selector : "#wprsspostprepend",
            setup: function (editor) {
                editor.on('init', function () {
                    var pre = tinyMCE.get('wprsspostprepend');
                    var content = pre.getContent();
                    selector.setContent("<div id='random-wrap'>");
                });
            }
        });
     }
});
```

Then just add a closing div tag via the append attribute

Comment: Why the downvote? At least say why my post is so cr@ppy in your opinion.

Comment: Wasn't my downvote, I appreciated your answer and it solved my problem! on a side note I do have an issue with the downvote system here :)

Comment: @Top-Bot Sorry, it wasn't aimed at you. It was a general shout of rage in the hope that the downvoter might see it and at least give a reason for their ridiculous downvote. Any chance you could upvote to counter it?